# How does codeigniter load view files and pass variables through?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I've read through the source code but it seems a little cryptic. I'm just trying to get my head around how CI transforms an array into individual variables available to the view.

I gather that the view is included with include(), but the variables seem to only be effective for the view.

Controller:

```
$this->load->view('about', array('title' => 'about'));
```

View:

```
<?php echo $title; // shows 'about' ?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[php extract() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
$array = array('test' => 'val', 'key' => 'value');

extract($array);

var_dump($test);
var_dump($key);
```

The variables $test and $key would be "visible" in the view only if they are declared localy, so let's say a function includes the view file and right before including it, it will extract the values, then the variables would be visible only inside that function ( witch body would contain the view file too ), it's not realy how CI does it but it explains the principle .

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I've never heard of it before!